# When playing piano, how do you play fast successive notes between octaves using one hand?

Tags: piano

I know this music is too hard for me, but I'd like to work up to it. The largest problem with it for me right now is the left hand 16th notes. I would like to know how I can effectively play the left hand notes? http://sheethost.com/sheet/ci6RSp

Comment: Well, you start by playing them realllyyyyyy slow, and then you very gradually make them faster.  At some point, if you do it often enough, you'll be able to play them at the speed you want.  This is pretty much true for anything you want to play fast someday.

Comment: You might put a snippet of a measure showing the technique in your question to prevent link rot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something that has helped me immensely with this is visualization. You can look at the keyboard, but try to IMAGINE how your hand should move. Make sure that your hand position between the two octaves doesn't change too much, and that your hand is moving fluidly (not jerky). Try to maintain good wrist technique. This sort of thing is hard for every pianist to learn, but gradually will become easy over time.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that, also do you have any tips for playing descending notes? I'm mostly fine and fluid with ascending notes, but I am really awkward with notes going down.

Comment: Most likely it's because you've practiced ascending more. Start at the top of the keyboard and work your way down.